# How to get barcode data with barcode reader details

Tags: c#, barcode-scanner

I am working on C#.
I am creating application which takes input from multiple barcode reader via USB.So,i want to know that from which reader i am getting value

Comment: So, can you show the code you have written so far? We can't help you if we don't know how exactly you are reading data from these barcode readers.

Answer (score 0):

Bar code scanners work by letting the system think their input comes from the keyboard.
So, one way of doing this:
bar code scanners can be programmed to send pre- and or suffixes with every scan.
You could prefix every scan with the e.g. 'F12' key for one scanner and with the 'F11' key for the other scanner. In the main form of your application, in the keypreview event, you scan for 'F12' and 'F11' keys, and if one comes in, you pop up a modal dialog with a textbox that has the focus. The rest of the scanned characters will end up in the textbox of that dialog. If on top op that, you also program an 'Enter' keysequence as a suffix to the scanned code, it would automatically close that dialog (if the dialog is well built). One of the advantages of this pattern is that, if a code is not readable, you can press F11 or F12, and the dialog will pop up and you can manually type the number.

Comment: If setting the scanner is not an option(people in here would give me the stare down shall I ask them to `set` anything up.)...  Then you can setup a double scan process where the operator first scans the "station" barcode, then performs the actual product scan. You can then concatenate both scans and there's your value.